# Using PHP and MySQL to create an image selection form

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to have a form that when you select the radio button it will select the image and query into the server; now I'm not quite sure as to how this would be accomplished because when I select any other then the original it doesn't seem to work.
My form Code (Well. The important part)

```
<form action="update_image.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="Index" />
<td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="images/cartoon/2ofus.png" /></center></td>
<td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="img src='images/cartoon/3lb_Bruce.png" /></center></td>
<td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="img src='images/cartoon/bearry.png" /></center></td>
<td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="img src='images/cartoon/Bemmer.png" /></center></td>
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
   </form>
```

My Query is as follows:

```
$link     = mysqli_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass", "$webdb");
    $page = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['page']);
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['image']);
$query = "UPDATE `pages` 
              SET `image`='<$image>' 
              WHERE `name`='$page'";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

It's not the best in the world, but overall I think it should work solidly, but it doesn't, so if anyone might know why it'd be great. Thanks.

The first  Is the original. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I select any other then the original" ? Which is the original one?

Comment: Added Clarification to the post. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Is there a reason why the value of the others is different than the value of the first(`img src='some_relative_url`)?

Comment: Yes. It's a form to actually change the image on the home page while logged in as an admin. I found a work around since SQL and PHP weren't getting along with me by echoing on the index page with `code`echo "<img src='"; echo $row['image']; echo "'>";`code` It's not the best in the world, but it works.

Comment: That doesn't explain why your options, 2-4 are different than option 1 in value.  By your explanation, your image tag would then render as `<img src="img src='someurl" />`.

Comment: Something I hadn't even noticed, it wasn't supposed to be that way it was a typo while I was retyping into SOF. Sorry, the img src= wasn't supposed to be in 2-4.

Comment: Do you mind then if I edit the above so there isn't any confusion from others?  Secondly, can you please post your other code?  I don't see anything immediately wrong with what you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understood from your question. You have a specific image in the home page, whose src is queried from the database and can be updated by the form given by you.

Change the form to :

```
 <form action="update_image.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="page" value="Index" />
  <td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="images/cartoon/2ofus.png" /></center>   </td>
  <td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="images/cartoon/3lb_Bruce.png" /></center></td>
  <td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="images/cartoon/bearry.png" /></center></td>
 <td><center><input name="image" type="radio" value="images/cartoon/Bemmer.png" /></center></td>
 <input type="submit" value="Update" />
```

Change the query to:

```
  $query = "UPDATE `pages` 
          SET `image`='$image' 
          WHERE `name`='$page'";
```

In the index page, after querying the tables pages, use the result in the image tag like :

```
 print "<img src='{$row['image']}'/>";
```

Comment: Their form was already like that.  They state as much in the comments.

Comment: @Daedalus : Noticed that comment after posting the answer. Looks like he was printing the <img> tag wrong. Anyhow, should I remove the form part?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious mistake is the naming of your variables, you assign the value of the radio-button to `$content` and then in your query you are using `<$image>`. That should just be `$content` without the `<` and `>`.

Apart from that you should add error handling, for example `mysqli_error($link)` will give you the last error.